# How to add Javascript code on the head tag, for only success page,

Tags: php, javascript

I hope I explain my self correctly.

I need to include 2 JS.  The first JS code needs to be in all pages of the site.
I could try doing that in 2 ways:

1. header.phtml
2. Miscellaneous scripts through magento configuration, design, head.

that would work perfectly fine for the firs script.

```
<script>/*DO NOT ALTER *** */(function(e){var t="1340",n=document,r,i,s={http:"http://cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js",https:"https://secure-cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js"},o=s[/\w+/.exec(window.location.protocol)[0]];i=n.createElement("script"),i.type="text/javascript",i.async=!0,i.src=o+"#"+t,r=n.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],r.parentNode.insertBefore(i,r),i.readyState?i.onreadystatechange=function(){if(i.readyState==="loaded"||i.readyState==="complete")i.onreadystatechange=null}:i.onload=function(){try{e()}catch(t){}}})(function(){});</script>
```

However, I am required to do the following on the success page,

http://screencast.com/t/ze0b43gjUyWV

I already know how to generate the script dinamically based on:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219799/how-to-integrate-dinamically-js-code-in-success-page-in-magento

but I dont know how to include that code only on the head tag of success page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take [the code that @cyk provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25219918/158766) and save it to `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cj/udo.phtml`.

Then, in your `local.xml` layout file, add the following:

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/template" name="cj_udo" template="app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cj/udo.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

If your site allows multi-address shipping, you'll also want to add this:

```
<checkout_multishipping_success>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/template" name="cj_udo" template="app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cj/udo.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_multishipping_success>
```

Those layout handles ensure the code will only be added on the success page(s).

Comment: amazing, I will try it soon

Comment: where can I find layout.xml?

Comment: I meant local.xml layout file?4

Comment: I am having issues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228365/not-valid-template-file-in-magento

Answer (score 1):

See [Magento - add inline javascript to product page via layout update xml code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906109/magento-add-inline-javascript-to-product-page-via-layout-update-xml-code)

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="your.block.name">
           <action method="setText">
              <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">/*DO NOT ALTER *** */(function(e){var t="1340",n=document,r,i,s={http:"http://cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js",https:"https://secure-cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js"},o=s[/\w+/.exec(window.location.protocol)[0]];i=n.createElement("script"),i.type="text/javascript",i.async=!0,i.src=o+"#"+t,r=n.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],r.parentNode.insertBefore(i,r),i.readyState?i.onreadystatechange=function(){if(i.readyState==="loaded"||i.readyState==="complete")i.onreadystatechange=null}:i.onload=function(){try{e()}catch(t){}}})(function(){});</script>]]></text>
           </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```