# Adding JS File in head.phtml

Tags: javascript, head

I'm trying to add a js file to the head section of my file and am not sure if I'm following procedure here. What I have done is gone into the head.phtml file and placed the path to the js file below this block of code as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getTranslatorScript() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="HoverAlls/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

In chrome develop tools, I see that it is in the head section but I'm getting a 404 on the path. I have double checked that the path is correct, so I'm wondering if there is another way to do this?

Sorry, I'm a noob!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add js files like that.
You should use the layout files.
Add this in one of your layout files.

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <js>path/to/js.js</js> <!-- the path is relative to the `js` folder in your magento instance. You should add your jquery file in that folder. -->
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: again... way too fast. So adding a comment for a nice source http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2013/10/24/adding-javascript-and-css-files-to-head-section-of-magento.html

Comment: Awesome. This worked great. Love learning something new!

Comment: So if I need to add actual script and not call a js file, what do I do?

    <script>
$(window).load(function(){
$('.HoverAlls_Caption').HoverAlls({
"mode" : "caption",
"coords" : "0,0||0,0||0,0",
"text_coords" : "0,0||0,0||0,0"
});
});
</script>

Comment: @MattJones See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906109/magento-add-inline-javascript-to-product-page-via-layout-update-xml-code

Comment: @MattJones. See this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/31817/146. Just replace `<checkout_multishipping_success>` with `default`

Comment: I'm not understanding the "your.block.name" portion of the code.

Comment: @MattJones If just a block name so you can access it by name (just give it a unique name) eg if you want to remove it for a specific page then you could do  `<reference name="header"><remove name="your.block.name"/> ..`